# CTE after UNION ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

This query does not work:

```
WITH a AS 
(SELECT 1 AS c1)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    a 


UNION ALL

WITH b AS 
(SELECT 1 AS c1)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    b
```

Could you help, please?

Real query uses tables, but it is not essential in the example.

Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
;WITH a AS 
(SELECT 1 AS c1), 
b AS 
(SELECT 1 AS c1)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    a 
UNION ALL
SELECT
    *
FROM
    b
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: you're breaking the query ;-)

Let me explain:

- The UNION key word takes 2 "queries" and makes them into one.
- The WITH key word can't be used inside a query and it is only valid for one query
- WITH can be used to define multiple CTEs

The result of all of these is that you want to define both of the CTEs (a & b) before the UNION query.
Putting the WITH inside the UNION query breaks the UNION (since WITH is always outside of (before) a query.